# Authentication And Authorization Identity + JWT via Web-API 2 for several ASP.NET MVC webclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have this web-api that has `Identity + JWT` Configuration within. so basically if i have to authenticate someone they have to send request to my api and i generate this jwt token and send them my identity roles and user information and etc. there are several clients that are using this (for example there are a vue.js app and react.js app) they are working with and it's fine. but now there is a `ASP.NET MVC 5` that wants to use this webapi and the identity service and i was not sure how to work with it.
I've tried identity where within app start you include dbcontext and the built in function like `Authorize(role="etc")` attribute works perfectly because the identity uses it's own entity framwork to get them, however now i don't want the ASP.NET MVC App to see my DbContext Directly and that there is only one jwt token instead of all of them how can i manage the get authorize attribute working?
I've read many posts on stackoverflow about this issue but they only made me more confused. can someone point me in a right direction?